# How can I execute a command with "sudo" in a python/bash/ruby script via SSH?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

On a remote server I can execute a certain command only via "sudo". The authentication is done via a certificate. So when I login via SSH by a bash script, python, ruby or something else, how can I execute a certain command with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is using a configuration management solution, like `ansible`, You can use `become` directive to run `script/command` with `sudo privileges` from  a remote client.

If there is only one box or you need to schedule, you can use `/etc/crontab` and run it with `root` user at desired interval.

Comment: You can schedule with root privileges, Or use `sudo python script.py` from the command line. or `ssh` with `root` user to the remote box.

Comment: none of that will work. it's not schedulable. the python script is executed by a local user on a local computer. and logging as a root isn't what I need.